# Same li ul tag data is getting formed for every value in JSON Array

Tags: jquery

```
var products = [
    {
        "orderid": "14062313",
        "name": "Regular, 50 Ml",
        "image": "http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
        "quantity": "3",
        "price": "225",
        "toppings": [
            {
                "name": "Quantity      1",
                "value": [
                    "Belongs to Quantity 1"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Quantity      2",
                "value": [
                    "Belongs to Quantity 2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Quantity      3",
                "value": [
                    "Belongs to Quantity 3"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var divhtml = $('<div id="ordersummdiv">');
    var itemcart;
    for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
        var itemname = products[j].name;
        var topps = products[j].toppings;
     if (topps.length > 0) {
            var uitaghtml = '<ul>';
            for (var j = 0; j < topps.length; j++) {
                uitaghtml += '<li>' + topps[j].value + '</li>';
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < topps.length; j++) {
                itemcart = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap"> \
                    <div class="orderTitle">' + topps[j].name + '</div> \
                    <div class="orderCont"> \
                        <div class="orderPrice"> \
                             ' + uitaghtml + '</ul> \
                        </div> \
                    </div> \
                </div>';
                divhtml.append(itemcart);
                $("#orders").append(divhtml);

            }
        }
    }
});

<body>
<div id="orders">
</div>
</body>
```

With the above program , i am getting output as

```
Quantity 1
Belongs to Quantity 1
Belongs to Quantity 2
Belongs to Quantity 3


Quantity 2
Belongs to Quantity 1
Belongs to Quantity 2
Belongs to Quantity 3


Quantity 3
Belongs to Quantity 1
Belongs to Quantity 2
Belongs to Quantity 3
```

**I was expecting output as below**

```
Quantity 1

Belongs to Quantity 1




Quantity 2

Belongs to Quantity 2


Quantity 3

Belongs to Quantity 3
```

Could anybody please let me know how to fix this ??

Comment: Could any body please let me know how to fix this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the inner list *once*, including *all* of the value elements. Then you're reusing it for each topping. It's doing just what you told it to do.

This is more like it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  var itemname = products[i].name;
  var topps = products[i].toppings;

   for ( var j = 0; j < topps.length; j++ )
   {
        var uitaghtml = '<ul>' +
             '<li>' + topps[j].value + '</li>' +
            '</ul>';
            itemcart = '<div class="order-listdetails-wrap"> \
                <div class="orderTitle">' + topps[j].name + '</div> \
                <div class="orderCont"> \
                    <div class="orderPrice"> \
                         ' + uitaghtml + ' \
                    </div> \
                </div> \
            </div>';
            divhtml.append(itemcart);
            $("#orders").append(divhtml);

        }
    }
```